# getting dynamic values from html form to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript to add element dynamically.
Here count is defined and increasing by one

```
<span style="margin-left:10px;">File Type : <select name="select_type_'+count+'" >
<option value="select">Select</option></span>
```

I using an another javascript function to get the value of select_type_'+count+' by using

```
var temp=parseInt((document.submission.select_type_+i.value));
alert(temp);
```

here var `i` is defined and incrementing

but i am getting `NaN` value .how to solve this?thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create a fiddle inlcuding your function jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var temp=parseInt((document.submission['select_type_'+i].value));
alert(temp);
```

The JavaScript parser interprets your original code as `document.submission.select_type` plus `i.value`. Since neither `document.submission.select_type` nor `i.value` are defined, you're getting `NaN` from `parseInt`.